# How to update the old fragment in the Fragment list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I need to update the old fragment in the Fragment list, so I need to clear all the old style.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add()
```

method could add fragment to the list, but how to clear all the fragment once for all ?

Add

```
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
       .findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (fragment == null) {
        Log.d("Main",tag+"fragment == null");

        fragment = new FragmentFactory().getFragment(tag);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(currentFragment)
       .add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag).commit();
        currentFragment = fragment;
    } else if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        Log.d("Main",tag+"fragment.isHidden()");  
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .hide(currentFragment).show(fragment).commit();
        currentFragment = fragment;
    }
```

As the answer

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

its still existing bug, when the second round of the if statement it goes into the **else**. But as the purpose **fragment** should be cleared. The if statement need to go **if** branch and **add** new fragment.
How to fix it?

Comment: @Dhaval Patel,@uttami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: What  is null's  meaning?

Comment: i have found no proper documentation for this.what i can say this at this place of ''null'' fragment tag is passed to pop the related fragment.like.. if (tag.equals("4thfragment")) { if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) { fragmentManager.popBackStack("3rdfragment", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); } }